# Trouble choosing correct flag type

Tags: discussion, flags

I wanted to flag this question from the review stack but was unsure which flag to use.

My first thought was off-topic but I ended up going with 'Too broad'.

The description of Off-topic is a bit confusing to me, maybe it's just me though..

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion based, ect...

The incomplete catches me up everytime. Shouldn't the question below contain at least a small bit of code, what they tried, what failed, ect???

What flag type would you guys have chosen?

Actual question content

> I want to create a menu script with multi choice .
>   like :
>
> 1)
>
> 2)
>
> 3)
>
> 4)
>
> 5)
>
> i can choose 1 ,and 3 ,and 5 in the same time .
>
> please help me .

<strike>My flag is still pending so we will see...</strike>

**Flag was disputed.**

Comment: Disputed flags don't hurt you.  Someone else just disagreed with you, that's all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fully agree with Roombatron5000's answer. But I think it might be useful to give some more direction on when to use which flag:

- **Unclear what you're asking**: Well, it's pretty much what the name says. The standard case is that you read the question, and there isn't nearly enough detail to know what exactly the poster needs. In the worst case, there is some text, but it doesn't really contain a question.
- **Too Broad**: You understand what the poster wants, but it can't be answered reasonably within the format of the site. For example, somebody could ask a question "How do I write a game engine?", and might even provide good detail about what they want to achieve. Still, even if you understand exactly what they're looking for, this is a topic that fills entire books. There's just no way to give detailed directions in a few paragraphs.

In reality, you will often find questions that have symptoms of both. They are typically kind of vague, which makes "Unclear" a valid flag. But it's also fairly obvious that they would be "Too Broad" even if the poster fixed the question to be much clearer. In cases like this, you choose the flag that you think fits better, but both can be valid options.

In the example you quote, I do think that "Unclear" is the better fit. It's most definitely unclear. There's no clear definition of how it's supposed to behave, and really no question or problem statement.

On the other hand, it seems likely, or at least plausible, that the question could be answered within the SO format if it contained the necessary detail and problem statement. It's probably a fairly small and contained problem if they fixed the question to be more precise. It seems completely reasonable that you could write an answer that helps somebody with a shell script to choose between menu options. In that sense, I don't think it's "Too Broad".

Answer (score 6):

I would use **Unclear what you're asking** for this one. Because it's unclear what ***specifically*** the user is wanting to do.

Too broad would be a fine reason as well, but unclear what you're asking is more appropriate in this case, in my opinion.

Although you should always try your best to pick the correct flag reason, when it comes to flagging "as this question should be closed", the disputed/declined/helpful flag results are only determined based on if the question was closed or not, *not on if you chose the right reason*. So no need to worry too much about which one you choose if a question fits multiple close reasons.